# html custom element make host css apply to shadow dom child instead

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom, custom-element

So, I'm currently working on a custom element which I want to later be able to style using css just like a normal html element. However, the way my element is set up, some css styles like padding break the element when applied to the element itself - instead, they need to be applied to an element inside of the custom element's shadow dom in order to work. So my question is: **How can I make user-defined css on the custom element apply to an element in its shadow dom instead?**

To illustrate this, say the custom element is used in the following code:

```
<my-element style="padding:10px">Content here</my-element>
```

Typically, with the shadow dom I'm using this would result in the following flattened dom tree:

```
<my-element style="padding:10px">
    <div>
        Content here
    </div>
    Some other elements here
</my-element>
```

But I want the flattened dom tree to look something like this:

```
<my-element>
    <div style="padding:10px">
        Content here
    </div>
    Some other elements here
</my-element>
```

I've already tried a number of solutions, but so far none of them worked for me:

- applying `padding:inherit` to the inner element - this only works if I keep the padding on the parent element too, but I need it to be 0 (or somehow have the child elements ignore the parents padding while still being relatively positioned, but I don't think that's possible)
- using a css variable `--padding` to set the padding on the inner element - this would technically work, but it would require the user of the custom element to specifiy `--padding` instead of just `padding`, making the element less nice to use
- listening for changes to the padding using a script - as far as I know, there's no way to get notified when the computed style of the element changes, so I would have to keep checking periodically in order for this to work, potentially slowing down the page. Just listening for changes to `element.style` wouldn't work if, for example, a new css sheet is loaded that affects the custom element's padding.

Comment: Would injecting a global stylesheet into shadowDOM work for you? Make it disabled in the  main  DOM with: ``<style id="injectMe" onload="this.disabled=true">....</style>``

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom attribute. Here is a basic example

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
     :host {
       display:inline-block;
     }
      div {
       padding: ${this.getAttribute('padding')};
    }`
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

```html
<custom-element padding="10px">text here</custom-element>
```

Or like this if you want to apply CSS:

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    const css = `
     :host {
       display:inline-block;
       padding:0!important;
     }
      div {
       padding: ${window.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue("padding")}; 
    }`
    this.styles = document.createElement('style');
    this.styles.innerHTML = css;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.shadow.appendChild(this.styles);
    this.shadow.appendChild(div);
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

```css
custom-element {
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<custom-element >text here</custom-element>
```

Comment: I guess that's one way to do it, but it's still not as easy to use as just css - for example, you have to specify it on each element and can't just use css to select all elements of that type. +1 for the code example though

Comment: *ou have to specify it on each element* --> this is what your example is showing, you are using inline styles so you are already doing this

Comment: I already tried using getComputedStyle, the problem is that there's no way for me to detect when the computed style changes.

Answer (score -1):

If padding is all you need to allow the user to control and you need it to not break the layout, specify box-sizing...

```
host {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then the user of the element can adjust the padding in the traditional fashion without blowing it out...and no need to add the extra div.

Comment: That works for not breaking the elements width and height, but there are some other reasons to not have the padding on the element directly as well. I don't want "Some other elements" in my example code to be affected by the padding, and also the outer element is scrollable in my case so having a padding on it behaves inconsistently across browsers.

Answer (score -3):

**It is very simple.**

for the **CSS**, just set the

```
/* force to clear padding of the element */    
my-element { padding:0px !important; clear:both; } 

/* this indicate the first div found inside the element */
my-element > div:first-child { padding:10px; }
```

That's it. It should work.

Comment: I don't think you've fully unterstood the question - of course I could just add padding to the div like that myself, but I want the user to be able to control how much padding there is, so I'm looking for a way to have the div always have the padding that is specified on the the custom element.

Comment: The best practice is to only use ```!important``` when everything else has been done and failed.